# Microsoft Access Report Filter / how...?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database to calculate my expenses. I record expenses with negative numbers, and salary with positive numbers. When I make the month report, and sum the values, it sums it all including salary. I want to code of Visual Basic to sum negative numbers only. I know about Filter property, but the Filter I put disappears when I close database. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your report using a query or use the Where argument of the OpenReport method of the DoCmd object in versions of Access since 2003.

EDIT re comment

The easiest way to create a query is to use the query designer, viewed in SQL View, you should see something on the lines of:

```
 SELECT Amount 
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Amount <=0
```

Comment: what is criteria of query please?